# FileUplaod : A required anti-forgery token was not supplied or was invalid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, file-upload

I'm trying to do an upload file in my ASP.NET MVC 2 web application but I got an error.
A required anti-forgery token was not supplied or was invalid.

There is my aspx code :

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("ImportFile", "Suivi", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{ %>
   <input type="file" id="fileUpload" name="fileUpload" />
   <input type="submit" value="Import" />
<% } %>
```

And there is my method in my controller :

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult ImportFile(HttpPostedFileBase fileUpload)
    {
        if( fileUpload == null)
        {
            //Process files
        }
        return View();
    }
```

And there is the error stack :

```
A required anti-forgery token was not supplied or was invalid.
at System.Web.Mvc.ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute.OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAuthorizationFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
```

So where is my problem ?

Cheers

Skilpit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller action is decorated with the `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attribute meaning that it will try to validate the token. So you need to include this token inside the form using the [`Html.AntiForgeryToken`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470175.aspx) helper:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("ImportFile", "Suivi", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{ %>
    <%= Html.AntiForgeryToken() %>
   <input type="file" id="fileUpload" name="fileUpload" />
   <input type="submit" value="Import" />
<% } %>
```